# Upgrading from TFS 2017 to Azure Devops Server and changing the domain at the same time. Possible?

Tags: upgrade, azure-devops-server-2020, tfs-2017

We're upgrading from TFS 2017 to Azure Devops Server shortly. I've gone through several trials and everything has gone better than expected - super easy. But there's a new wrinkle. The new machine will be on a different domain than the old one. Initially I was thinking I'd just have to add back the users under this new domain, but I just realized that every object (bug, query, change request, etc.) in the instance has an owner that will most likely be tied to the the old domain.

Has anyone attempted this before? Any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Will all of those objects just become orphans or is there some way to associate them with the new domain account? Anything else I need to think about that I could be forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a utility that does this:

```
TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain:OldComputerorDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName
```

Haven't tried it yet. I'll update this response if it doesn't work.